# std::stringstream Not Converting String To Int Correctly

Tags: c++, arrays, char, int, stringstream

I am trying to convert a CharArrayPtr to int format, which I have managed to do so;

```
    std::string str;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberofvalues; i++)
    {   



        str = cmemblock[i];
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream <<str;
        int n;
        if (!(stream >>n)){

        }

        cout << n<<endl;
        }
```

However, the issue I am having is if I were to `cout << str;` It will display characters exactly how it is displayed in the .txt file. Unfortunately after the conversion to int format the output is not as expected, I will demonstrate below;

```
cout << str;
```

Displays this;

```
11
22
33
44
55
66
77
88
99

cout << n;
```

displays this;

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
5
6
6
6
7
7
7
8
8
8
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
```

I'm not entirely sure as of why this is happening but I believe the code I have entered is not coded correctly to interpret a new line perhaps?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem.  See here for an example using your code: https://ideone.com/Xestb9

Comment: Im not using C++11, not sure if that makes a difference? Visual Studio 2010 im afraid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberofvalues; i++)
```

The problem was here, this was amended to the correct value and has now been solved.